# Unable to send data to laravel using ionic 2

Tags: php, angular, laravel-5, ionic2

I am working on a Hybrid application I want to sent json data to laravel php server using Ionic 2.
 I am continuously getting error as

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.0.101:8000/SaveUsers.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Ionic Code:
register-recipient-page.ts

```
this.registrationService.sendData(this.donarDetails,this.recipientDetails).subscribe(
        response => console.log(response), // success
        error => console.log(error),       // error
        () => console.log('completed')     // complete
     );
```

Ionic Code:
registration.service.ts

```
 sendData(recipient,donar): Observable<Object> {

        let encoded_data = JSON.stringify({recipientDetails:recipient, donarDetails:donar});
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8');
        headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT,DELETE, OPTIONS');
        //let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
         console.log(encoded_data);
        return this.http.post( 'http://192.168.0.101:8000/SaveUsers',encoded_data, options).map(
            (res: Response) => res.json() || {}
        );

    }
```

laravel: web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function(){
 Route::get('/SaveUsers', 'UserController@saveUser');
});
```

Cors.php

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next){
return $next($request)
->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT,DELETE, OPTIONS');
}
```

I tried to do testing using simple get on the same url without sending any data, it was working fine.
Please help!!!!

Comment: U r working with chrome then install this extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Comment: and add the header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT,DELETE, OPTIONS'); to the main page of php which is redirecting to other pages

Comment: @rashidnk I have installed the extension. That didn't worked. Even I have added those headers using middle ware in my route as you could see it in the code. Let me know if any thing I am missing